# Vue - same mutation refreshes (or not!) components depending on which component it is called from?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have problem understanding why THE SAME mutation fails to refresh data displayed in components (although it does change underlying vuex store data!) if it is called from one of the components, but it does refresh the data if called from another component?

I am updating `Filter` objects stored in store this way: `state.report.filters[]`, where `filters` is array of `Filter` objects.

```
const state = {
    report: {
        filters: [], // array of Filter objects
        ...
    }
}
```

My mutation looks for a filter in the array and substitutes the whole Filter object.

```
const mutations = {
    setFilter: (state, newFilterValue) => {
        let changedFilter = state.report.filters.find(filter => {
            return filter.fieldName === newFilterValue.fieldName;
        });
        changedFilter = newFilterValue;
    }
}
```

The mutation is called from a method of Filter class defined like this (separate module):

```
import { store } from './store';
export class Filter {
    constructor ({
        ...
    } = {}) {
       this.operators = []; // Array of Operator objects
       this.value = []; // Array of values - in this case Dates
    };    
    updateOperator (operatorName) { // this mutation refreshes components when executed
        this.operator[0] = new Operator(operatorName);
        store.commit('setFilter', this); // whole object passed to the mutation
    };
    updateValue (newValue) { // this mutation changes store value, but fails to refresh components
        this.value[0] = newValue; // newValue is a Date
        store.commit('setFilter', this);
    };
};
```

The app displays data in rows (each `Filter` has a separate row), each row contains cells, of which one contains components dedicated to `Filter`'s value and Operator. These dedicated components receive as props callback functions which are methods of the `Filter` object. They execute the callback functions when a new value is entered passing the value to the `Filter` which then updates a relevant property and calls the mutation passing in both cases the whole Filter object as payload.

```
// TABLE CELL COMPONENT displaying filter value and operator
<template> 
   <td>
    <operator-component
      :iconName="proppedFilterObject.operator.iconName"
      :callback="proppedFilterObject.updateOperator.bind(proppedFilterObject)"
    ></operator-component>
    <value-component
      :date="proppedFilterObject.value[0]"
      :callback="proppedFilterObject.updateValue.bind(proppedFilterObject)"
    ></value-component>
  </td>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['proppedFilterObject'] // whole filter object
};
</script>

// OPERATOR COMPONENT
<template>
  <div @click.stop="chooseOperator">
     {{ iconName }} // some operator value display
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        chooseOperator () {
            const modal = new ChooseOperatorModal({
                callback: this.callback // this displays another modal for receiving data. The modal calls the callback.
            });
        },
    },
    props: ['callback', 'iconName']
};
</script>

// VALUE COMPONENT
<template>
  <date-picker v-model="computedDate"> // THIRD PARTY COMPONENT
  </date-picker>
  {{ date }} // additional display to verify if there's a problem within 'date-picker'
</template>

<script>
import DatePicker from 'vue2-datepicker'; // THIRD PARTY COMPONENT
export default {
    components: { DatePicker },
    computed: {
        computedDate: {
            get: function () {
                return this.date;
            },
            set: function (newValue) {
                this.callback(newValue);
            }
        }
    },
    props: ['callback', 'date']
};
</script>
```

So, if eg. I enter new operator value from Operator component, everything refreshes. When I enter a new value in the value component, the mutation is executed and store value changed, but displayed data are not refreshed. However, if afterwards I change an operator all the components will refresh and value will get displayed. Even if I change operator in a different Filter object(!). Ie:

a) Change in report.filters[0].value - display not refreshed, but...

b) then change report.filters[1].operator - both report.filters[1].operator AND PREVIOUSLY CHANGED report.filters[0].value get refreshed(?!).

What can be a reason of such behaviour? Where to look for the problem?

Some additional remarks:

1) I am using a third party component "vue2-date-picker" for date choice and display. However it does not seem to be responsible for the problem, as if I try to display the new value just in `{{ }}` notation it behaves the same way. I have used the date picker in other components and there it functions correctly as well.

2) In the code samples I left out most imports/exports and other seemingly irrelevant elements to keep the question reasonably short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with the code and several of them are contributing to the problems you're seeing. A full, thorough answer that addresses all of these problems would be ridiculously long so instead I will skim through them without going into huge amounts of detail. You will need to do some further reading and experimentation to understand each of these topics properly.

Let's start with this line in the mutation:

```js
changedFilter = newFilterValue;
```

This line assigns a new value to the local variable `changedFilter`. That's all. As it's the last line of the mutation the net result is that it doesn't really do anything.

Presumably your intent was to update the array `state.report.filters`, replacing the old entry with a new entry. However, just updating a local variable isn't going to do that.

At this point you may be wondering *'If that doesn't do anything, then why is the state in my store changing?'*. I'll come to that in a moment but first let me prove to you that your existing code does nothing.

Try removing the code inside `setFilter` completely. Just leave an empty function. Then try clicking around in the UI just like you did before. You'll find that the store state updates just the same as it did before, even though you've removed the code to update the array.

The correct way to implement that mutation would be to use `findIndex` to find the relevant index and then use either `Vue.set` or the array's `splice` method to update the array accordingly. That will change the item in the array. However...

This brings us back to the earlier question. Why is the state updating if the mutation does nothing?

This is because you're using the same object in multiple places. The `Filter` object held in the array is the same object that your UI is editing. There are no copies being taken, there is just a single object. So when you change the properties of that object inside `updateOperator` or `updateValue` this will immediately be reflected inside the store. Calling the `setFilter` mutation is just asking the store to replace an object with itself.

There's nothing specific to Vue about this. This is just the standard behaviour of reference types in JavaScript. It is also common with many other programming languages that don't directly expose *pointers*. It can be useful to learn a little about how pointers work in other languages as it will give you a better initial mental model before attempting to understand how reference types behave in JavaScript. Understanding the difference between 'by value' and 'by reference' may also be a useful starting point.

The next topic to cover is reactivity, which very much is a Vue topic.

Specifically, there are certain changes that Vue can't detect. These are usually referred to as the reactivity *caveats*. You can find more about them in the official documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

There are at least two lines in your code that violate these rules:

```js
this.operator[0] = new Operator(operatorName);
```

and

```js
this.value[0] = newValue;
```

You can't set array entries directly by index. The array will update but it won't trigger any reactive dependencies within Vue. Instead you need to use either `Vue.set` or one of the array methods, e.g. `push`, `pop`, `splice`, etc.. In this example you could use `splice`.

e.g. Using `Vue.set`:

```js
Vue.set(this.value, 0, newValue);
```

e.g. Using `splice`:

```js
this.value.splice(0, 0, newValue);
```

Why does all of this matters?

Well Vue will only re-render a component if its reactive dependencies have changed. They are very similar to computed properties in that regard. Here's how it works...

Vue compiles the template down to a function. That function is referred to as the `render` function. When rendering a component Vue calls the `render` function and that function returns a description of how to render the component. Any reactive properties that are touched while that function is running will be recorded as dependencies. If, at some point in the future, the value of one of those reactive properties changes then Vue will rerun the `render` function to generate a new rendering of that component.

There are two key points to take out of this description:

1. If you fall foul of one of the reactivity caveats then Vue won't know the dependency has changed, so it won't re-render the component.
2. The `render` function runs as a whole. It doesn't just target a small chunk of the template, it always runs the whole thing.

So if you change a dependency in a non-reactive way (i.e. one of the caveats) it won't trigger a rendering update. But if you subsequently update a dependency properly, Vue will detect that and will rerun the `render` function. When it runs it will run the whole thing, so any new values will be picked up, even if they weren't detected when they changed.

It isn't immediately clear to me which rendering dependency is causing your component to re-render. However, it only needs one of them to change in a detectable manner. Any other changes will then get pulled in incidentally when the `render` function runs and reads their current values.

That covers why your code isn't working. However, I would also worry about your decision to introduce a `Filter` class. I understand how that may be appealing if you've come from some other OO environment but it isn't typically how Vue is used. It is possible to make it work but you will need a good understanding of both JavaScript reference types and the Vue reactivity system to avoid falling through the cracks. There is no reason why using a specific class to hold your data can't be made to work but in practice it usually ends up being less maintainable than not using such a class. A more typical Vue approach would be to use simple, anonymous objects/arrays to hold the data and then for the data owner (either a component or store module) to be responsible for making any mutations to that data. Events are used to pass changes up the component hierarchy rather than callback props.

Ultimately you will need to judge whether the `Filter` class is justified but it is probably not what future maintainers of your code will be expecting.

Comment: First of all thank you VERY MUCH for such an in-depth answer! I really appreciate it. Indeed changing that single `this.value[0] = newValue;` line into `splice` already fixed the problem. I will try to take into account what you wrote about arrays and review my understanding of Vue's reactivity. I’m a bit shocked though, as I used a similar pattern in many places in the app and for some reason it worked correctly. Although I usually looked up an object in an array and changed single property not whole object which apparently makes some difference.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted why parts of my code looked this way. I used that line that ‘does nothing’, as I believed that the reactivity is triggered by use of mutations. Vue’s documentation explicitly orders to use them for reactivity and testing that I performed some time ago seemed to confirm this(!). If I changed object’s property from within class method it wasn’t reactive, but if I used the pattern described here – it worked correctly. Surprisinlgy for me, if I change the value with the use of splice as you suggested – the mutation is no longer necessary the change is reactive anyway.

Comment: Finally, yes, I noticed that Vue is not ‘class-friendly’, however I initially tried to build the app without classes and it resulted in a mess and I have no ‘mentor’ I could learn from. Classes seem to work much better for me. Also the course I learned from (Academind’s) suggested against putting too much logic inside components. So if it can be done with classes, I’ll rather go the way of deeper understanding of Vue’s reactivity to avoid the cracks you mentioned. :) Anyway, again thank you very much for showing me the path that I should follow! :) And I will certainly do more testing.